# why not using strip_tags() to prevent xss attack instead of htmlspecialchars()?

Tags: xss, htmlspecialchars, strip-tags

If I need to display `$_GET` values in templates, why not using `strip_tags()` to prevent xss attack instead of `htmlspecialchars()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because strip_tags doesn't fix every possible abuse case. True, it fixes the worst offenders, but there are other cases, e.g. when inserting values back into `<input>` tags yourself, where the quotes can be broken out of.

Consider:
`<input type="text" value="my string" />`

If `my string` comes from some other data source that isn't XSS-protected, it could conceivable contain something like:
`"><script ....`

which can use the original closing `>` of the input tag - and `strip_tags` may or may not catch that case. I seem to remember it looks for `<` followed by `>` which wouldn't be found in the above string.

Comment: Thanks. Very useful answer. What about using both: `strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_GET))`? Make sense? Does strip_tags still work on escaped html special chars?

Comment: No because at that point it no longer contains `<` or `>` tags.

Comment: How about strip_tags first, then htmlspecialchars? I think this way, only in those particular cases as you mentioned there will remains tags yet and in most cases they will be removed so still better?

Comment: Yeah, that would work if you're going for the prettiest input you're going to get. I guess it depends what you're trying to achieve; if you plan on allowing basic formatting, you can't really strip_tags at any point.

Comment: no formatting should be in input in my code, inputs should just contain id, or string etc.

Comment: It really does depend on what you're expecting. If it's arbitrary user input without formatting, htmlspecialchars is the minimum you need (but can be rolled after strip_tags if you like). If it's specific user input like ids, you could sanitise against what characters are legal for those ids, e.g. `preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-]/i', '', $string)` to strip anything that isn't a-z, 0-9 or _ or - characters.

Answer (score 1):

htmlspecialchars() can escape all special characters which was able to add in example, a `<script>alert('You've been hacked');</script>`

The main part of a website secured is:

**htmlspecialchars() - To prevent XSS

MySQLI prepared statement - To prevent SQL injection**

There alot of other attack, but these two is a must for every website in the world, otherwise, i will be able to hack your website in 1 minute (no lie).